# Find the order of date group by

Tags: python, pandas, date

Suppose my dataset looks like this:

```
data = {'name':['A1','A2','A2','A1','A3','A3'],
        'date_create':['28-01-2020','15-02-2020','15-03-2020',
                       '25-03-2020','01-04-2020','30-05-2020']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to create a new column that indicate the order of month, group by each name. For example the customer A1 has 2 date '28-01-2020' and '25-03-2020', so the order of month for this name are 2 and 1 (the most recent are 1)

The result should looks like this:

```
   name date_create order
0   A1  28-01-2020  2
1   A2  15-02-2020  2
2   A2  15-03-2020  1
3   A1  25-03-2020  1
4   A3  01-04-2020  2
5   A3  30-05-2020  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.rank.html) with `method='dense'` and `ascending=False`:

```
df['date_create'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_create'])

df['rank'] = (df.groupby('name')['date_create']
                .rank(method='dense', ascending=False)
                .astype(int))
print (df)
  name date_create  rank
0   A1  2020-01-28     2
1   A2  2020-02-15     2
2   A2  2020-03-15     1
3   A1  2020-03-25     1
4   A3  2020-01-04     2
5   A3  2020-05-30     1
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can try:

```
df.date_create = pd.to_datetime(df.date_create)
df['order'] = df.sort_values(['name', 'date_create'], ascending=False).groupby('name')['date_create'].cumcount() + 1
df = df.sort_index()
```

###### OUTPUT:

```
  name date_create  order
0   A1  2020-01-28      2
1   A2  2020-02-15      2
2   A2  2020-03-15      1
3   A1  2020-03-25      1
4   A3  2020-01-04      2
5   A3  2020-05-30      1
```

Answer (score 1):

sort_values, groupby name and cuncount

```
df['order']=df.sort_values(by=['name', 'date_create']).groupby('name').cumcount()+1



    name date_create  order
0   A1  28-01-2020      2
1   A2  15-02-2020      1
2   A2  15-03-2020      2
3   A1  25-03-2020      1
4   A3  01-04-2020      1
5   A3  30-05-2020      2
```